# How to call another filter from within a ruby filter in logstash.

Tags: logstash, logstash-configuration

I'm building out logstash and would like to build functionality to anonymize fields as specified in the message.

Given the message below, the field `fta` is a list of fields to anonymize. I would like to just use `%{fta}` and pass it through to the anonymize filter, but that doesn't seem to work.

```
{  "containsPII":"True",  "fta":["f1","f2"],  "f1":"test",  "f2":"5551212" }
```

My config is as follows

```
 input {
  stdin { codec => json }
}

filter {
  if [containsPII] {
    anonymize {
      algorithm => "SHA1"
      key => "123456789"
      fields => %{fta}
    }
  }
}

output {
  stdout {
    codec => rubydebug
  }
}
```

The output is

```
{
    "containsPII" => "True",
            "fta" => [
        [0] "f1",
        [1] "f2"
    ],
             "f1" => "test",
             "f2" => "5551212",
       "@version" => "1",
     "@timestamp" => "2016-07-13T22:07:04.036Z",
           "host" => "..."
}
```

Does anyone have any thoughts? I have tried several permutations at this point with no luck.

Thanks,
-D

EDIT:
After posting in the Elastic forums, I found out that this is not possible using base logstash functionality. I will try using the ruby filter instead. So, to ammend my question, How do I call another filter from within the ruby filter? I tried the following with no luck and honestly can't even figure out where to look. I'm very new to ruby.

```
filter {
 if [containsPII] {
    ruby {
      code => "event['fta'].each { |item| event[item] = LogStash::Filters::Anonymize.execute(event[item],'12345','SHA1') }"
      add_tag => ["Rubyrun"]
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: `%{fta}` is how you would print a variable into a string. Have you tried `[fta]`, which is a reference to that variable?

Comment: Yes, I have. It anonymizes the data in the array FTA instead of the fields F1 and F2.

Answer (score 1):

You can execute the filters from ruby script. Steps will be:

- Create the required filter instance in the init block of inline ruby script.
- For every event call the filter method of the filter instance.
- Following is the example for above problem statement. It will replace my_ip field in event with its SHA1.
- Same can be achieved using ruby script file.
- Following is the sample config file.

  ```
  input { stdin { codec => json_lines } }
  filter {
    ruby {
      init => "
        require 'logstash/filters/anonymize'

        # Create instance of filter with applicable parameters
        @anonymize = LogStash::Filters::Anonymize.new({'algorithm' => 'SHA1', 
                                                       'key' => '123456789', 
                                                       'fields' => ['my_ip']})
        # Make sure to call register
        @anonymize.register                                                  
      "
      code => "
        # Invoke the filter
        @anonymize.filter(event)
      "
    }
  }
  output { stdout { codec => rubydebug {metadata => true} } }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I wasn't able to figure out how to call another filter from within a ruby filter, but I did get to the functional goal.

```
filter {
 if [fta] {
    ruby {
      init => "require 'openssl'"
      code => "event['fta'].each { |item| event[item] = OpenSSL::HMAC.hexdigest(OpenSSL::Digest::SHA256.new, '123456789', event[item] ) }"
    }
 }
}
```

If the field FTA exists, it will SHA2 encode each of the fields listed in that array.